# Is it an SEO mistake to not load loading google-analitics js for crawlers?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

Will not loading google-analitics js for crawlers cause problems?

Currently I want to stop loading some external js when a crawler explores my site. The easiest way for me would include not loading google-analytics.

Is this bad for SEO? I can't find much information about this.

Comment: That shouldn't be any issue as far as I know as long as your website functions normal and you don't manipulate content.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the Google Analytics script delaying your site load times, you can defer it.

You could also load it via the Google Tag Manager script which is the preferred method.